# What are these Errors / Warnings when running simple command line script

Tags: python, scripting, command-line, linux

I followed the [official documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_overview.html) to run a simple script:

```
import bpy
bpy.data.objects["Cube"].data.vertices[0].co.x += 1.0
```

by command

```
blender --python my_script.py
```

but I get the error:

```
Read prefs: /home/ubuntu1/.config/blender/2.82/config/userpref.blend
ERROR (rna.define): /build/blender-RL3axj/blender-2.82.a+dfsg/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_define.c:1697 RNA_def_property_ui_range: "RenderPovSettingsScene.media_diffusion_scale", precision outside range.
ERROR (rna.define): /build/blender-RL3axj/blender-2.82.a+dfsg/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_define.c:1697 RNA_def_property_ui_range: "RenderPovSettingsScene.media_absorption_scale", precision outside range.
WARN (rna.define): /build/blender-RL3axj/blender-2.82.a+dfsg/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_define.c:1647 RNA_def_property_ui_text: 'Positive values lead to scattering in the direction of the light and negative values lead to scattering in the opposite direction of the light. Larger values of e (or smaller values in the negative case) increase the directional property of the scattering.' description from 'media_eccentricity' '' ends with a '.' !
WARN (rna.define): /build/blender-RL3axj/blender-2.82.a+dfsg/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_define.c:1239 RNA_def_struct_ui_text: 'Export only files necessary to texture preview and render image.' description from 'TEX_OT_preview_update' '' ends with a '.' !
WARN (rna.define): /build/blender-RL3axj/blender-2.82.a+dfsg/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_define.c:1239 RNA_def_struct_ui_text: 'Use this class to define pov world buttons.' description from 'OBJECT_OT_light_preset_add' '' ends with a '.' !
WARN (rna.define): /build/blender-RL3axj/blender-2.82.a+dfsg/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_define.c:1239 RNA_def_struct_ui_text: 'Use this class to define pov radiosity add presets button.' description from 'SCENE_OT_radiosity_preset_add' '' ends with a '.' !
WARN (rna.define): /build/blender-RL3axj/blender-2.82.a+dfsg/source/blender/makesrna/intern/rna_define.c:1239 RNA_def_struct_ui_text: 'Use this class to create blender text editor operator to insert pov snippets like other pov IDEs.' description from 'TEXT_OT_povray_insert' '' ends with a '.' !
Registering panel class: 'TEXT_PT_POV_custom_code' misses category, please update the script
```

I have blender 2.82 on Ubuntu 20.04.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: These are errors / warnings created by one of the addons you have enabled.  POVRay perhaps.

Comment: @batFINGER you're absolutely right. It was resolved by disabling POV-Ray. What is the solution then? Is POV-Ray incompatible with python module?

Comment: Speculating (as I don't use POVRay) make sure you have the addon version to match your blender.  Or disable by default if not required by scripts.

Comment: @batFINGER again, you're right. I have pov3.8 but I think blender supports 3.7. I will test it.